# Ruby on Rails - Multiple Models Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have 5 models and I need to create a unique form that can create a new object for each model. The models are

```
Contract.rb
    belongs_to :establishment

Establishment.rb
    has_many :contracts
    belongs_to :address
    belongs_to :client

Address.rb
    has_many :establishments
    belongs_to :zip

Client.rb
    has_many :establishments

Zip.rb
    has_many :addresses
```

The form where the objects will be created is the form for the `Contract`

My first approach was creating fields_for each the other models, such as:

```
_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@contract) do |f| %>
<% if @contract.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@contract.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contract from being saved:</h2>
...#fields for contract
<%= f.fields_for @client do |client|%>
  <%=client.label 'Name'%><%=client.text_field :name%>
  ...#other fields for client
<%= f.fields_for @address do |address|%>
  <%=address.label 'Street'%><%=address.text_field :street%>
  ...#other fields for address
<%=f.fields_for @zip do |zip|%>
  <%=zip.label 'Code'%><%=zip.number_field :code%>
  ...#other fields for zip
```

The form was working fine and was getting all the fields but on the `ContractController.rb` I was unable to access the fields of the Address, Client and Zip on the params. If I use `@client = Client.create(params[:client])` it won't get an error but didn't not create an object on the Model. I realize that `params[:client]` (and the others params that not for the contract were NIL). I then used `params[:contract][:client]` and I get the error `ForbiddenAttributesError`...

So, I decided to change the approach and started thinking in multilevel nested_attributes but I'm still not getting...

I've changed the models to:

```
Contract.rb
    belongs_to :establishment
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :establishment

    has_one :address, through: :establishment
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

    has_one :zip, through: :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :zip

    has_one :client, :through => :establishment
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
```

and on the controller I've done

```
ContractController.rb

def new
  @contract = Contract.new
  @establishment = @contract.build_establishment
  @address = @establishment.build_address
  @zip = @address.build_zip
  @client = @establishment.build_client
end
```

but now the form doesn't have the fields for the `Client, Address and Zip`

Is it possible to create this type of form?

Comment: try changing `fields_for @client` to `fields_for :client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---EDITED ANSWER ----
removed the `_attributes` at the `[:contract][:client_attributes][:...]` (and :zip and :address)

G.B. was almost getting it but it wasn't enough.
Back to the first approach, after reading this [article](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) I made the following changes:

```
Contract
_form.html.erb

  <%= form_for(@contract) do |f| %>
  <% if @contract.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@contract.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this contract from                   being saved:</h2>
  ...#fields for contract
  <%= f.fields_for :client, @client do |client|%>
    <%=client.label 'Name'%><%=client.text_field :name%>
    ...#other fields for client
  <%= f.fields_for :address, @address do |address|%>
    <%=address.label 'Street'%><%=address.text_field :street%>
    ...#other fields for address
  <%=f.fields_for :zip, @zip do |zip|%>
    <%=zip.label 'Code'%><%=zip.number_field :code%>
    ...#other fields for zip
```

So, instead of `f.fields_for @client do |client|` it has to be `f.fields_for :client, @client do |client|` (and the same to the address and zip).

On the `ContractController`

```
def new
  @contract = Contract.new
  @client = Client.new
  @address = Address.new
  @zip = Zip.new
end

def create
  @contract = Contract.new(contract_params)

  if !Zip.exists?(:cod_postal1 => params[:contract][:zip][:cod_postal1], :cod_postal2 => params[:contract][:zip][:cod_postal2])
    create_zip
  elsif
    @zip = Zip.where(:cod_postal1 => params[:contract][:zip][:cod_postal1], :cod_postal2 => params[:contract][:zip][:cod_postal2])
  end

  create_client
  create_address
  @address.zip = @zip
  @establishment = Establishment.new(:sede => true)
  @establishment.address = @address
  @establishment.client = @client
  @client.save
  @address.save
  @establishment.save
  @contract.establishment = @establishment

  respond_to do |format|
    if @contract.save
    ...
end

def create_client
  @client = Client.create(
                          :numero => params[:contract][:client][:numero],
                          ...#other client fields
                         )
end

def create_zip
  @zip = Zip.create(
                    :distrito => params[:contract][:zip][:distrito],
                    :concelho => params[:contract][:zip][:concelho],
                    ...#other zip fields
  )      
end

def create_address
  @address = Address.create(
                            :rua => params[:contract][:address][:rua],
                            ...#other address fields
  )
end
```

And this does the trick. In one form with one submit button 5 different models are created

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use`accepts_nested_attributes_for`, keep this in mind from the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

"Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent"

So, it is invalid to say:

```
Class Contract #child class 
   belongs_to :establishment
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :establishment
```

because `Contract` is the `child`. Not the `Parent`.

The correct way of doing it is:

```
Class Establishment # parent class
    has_many :contracts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contracts
```

Then in your `Establishments` controller `params`, you'll add:

`contracts_attributes: [:id, attribute1, attribute2]` # don't forget to add :id

do the same approach for all the other models. Read the examples in the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Ok, keeping that in mind, is it possible to create this types of forms? Where the models are child or unrelated? It's hard for me to believe that ruby on rails won't be able able to make this work...

Comment: I'm not sure if you can update all 5 models from a single form. But you can nest together some of the forms. [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) will help you. It has good documentation with examples.